# In Java why is LocalDateTime not displaying time according to local timezone?

Tags: java, datetime

My code does this to display the current date and time

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
String formattedDate = dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now());
```

Because I use GMT anyway I didnt notice it always displaying using GMT timezone was reported by customer in different timezone. But I am confused because I thought LocalDateTime was the *local* datetime ?

Comment: Where does the time zone display come from? Does your date formatter `dtf` include a time zone?

Comment: no it doesnt, just updated question, should timezone be in the formatter or the dateTime ?

Comment: Because it ishowing thw wrong time

Comment: *"I thought LocalDateTime was the local datetime"* --- It is! It is local to the **JVM's** default time zone, just like the **documentation** says, i.e. the javadoc of [`now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--): *Obtains the current date-time from the system clock **in the default time-zone**.*

Answer (score 2):

`LocalDateTime` not have `Zone`, instead use `ZonedDateTime`:

```
String formattedDate = dtf.format(ZonedDateTime.now());
```

Beside, your `DateTimeFormatter` can't display the zone, to do this, you have to use `FormatStyle.LONG` instead of `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

> A date-time **without a time-zone**

If you want to have a `LocalDateTime` with a zone you can use `atZone()`:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = someLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String formattedDate = zdt.format(dtf);
```

Answer (score 2):

The customer is running your program on a system that has UTC configured as the default time zone.

You could tell the customer to change the time zone on the computer, or at least for your program specifically, but they probably won't do that. There are good reasons to run computers with the clock set to UTC.

Another solution might be to add the user's preferred time zone to your program settings, and use it consistently. For example:

```
String userPreferredTz = "Asia/Tokyo"; // Read from user preferences or settings file

ZoneId userZoneId = ZoneId.of(userPreferredTz);
dtf.format(ZonedDateTime.now(userZoneId))
```

Comment: Right so its just an error in users config, I cannot hardcode the the timezone because I have many customers al with different timezones.

Comment: They are using docker on a NAS, maybe docker is not picking up system timezone ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you hardcode the time zone. It's the opposite: I'm suggesting you make it configurable by the user.

Comment: That is a common issue with docker: it defaults to UTC and you have to jump through some hoops to pass in the host time zone. https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes https://forums.docker.com/t/synchronize-timezone-from-host-to-container/39116

Comment: But these links seem to show yo can hardcode a different timezone in the container or pass a different time zone as a parameter to the container, but this is beyond the abilities of my users is there no way for docker to automatically use the timezone of the host system ?

Comment: If there is one, nobody has found it. You can of course detect the host timezone with some scripting and then use the techniques from these posts to pass it to the container. But the way to detect the host timezone will depend on the OS

Answer (score 0):

> I thought LocalDateTime was the local datetime

This is correct. `LocalDateTime` is the local date-time i.e. using the system's default time-zone unless you specify a time-zone with it e.g. if you run the following statement on a machine set with `Europe/London` timezone, it will show the date-time in GMT and if you run it on a machine set with `Asia/Kolkata` timezone, it will show the date-time in IST (India Standard Time):

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
```

However, if you run the following statement on any machine, it will always give you the date-time of IST:

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")));
```

Since the `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` do not have a zone or offset information, you would like to use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` as per your requirement. The following table ([Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html)) gives you an overview of all the date-time classes and you can choose one from it as per your requirement:

[image]